# Gmail type javascript regex - allow no repetitions for invalid characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have email regex which I have succesfully done for a dot

```
/^[a-z0-9](\.?[a-z0-9]){0,}\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/i
```

it works perfect for emails, the only prob it has that it allows only dot and I want to allow underscore and hpyen too so I modified it to

```
/^[a-z0-9](_?-?\.?[a-z0-9]){0,}\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/i
```

and this fails succssfully for `abc.-sdf@def.sdf` but not for `abc-.sdf@def.sdf` and so

```
abc_-.sdf@def.sdf
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Um, what's invalid about those email addresses?

Comment: repetition about (. or _ or -)....any of these should not be repeated  even with each other. Its not taking -- or __ or two dots but it validates _- together

Comment: Who says you cannot have email addresses like that?  Just Gmail?

Comment: Gmail or even yahoo doesnt accept. No major brand accepts it. And the main problem is we dont want it :)

Comment: ...And if a user _does_ have an email address with those characters together?

Comment: Lee....No major brand accepts it

Comment: Oh, it's allowed in the email specification though.  Never mind.  So, why are you allowing whitespace at the end?

Comment: No we are not allowing any whitespace...

Comment: I have fixed it ...tnx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer -

```
/^[a-z0-9]((_|-|\.)?[a-z0-9]){0,}\@[[a-z0-9](-?[a-z0-9]){0,}.[a-z]{2,4}$/i,
```

Comment: You're allowing repeated underscores, hyphens and pluses (`+`) in the second half of the email address, I thought pluses wouldn't be permitted in the second half at all in practice.

Comment: Yes I came to know that later...its updated... the final one I made live

Answer (score 0):

How about:

`^(?!.*[._-]{2})[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.[\w.-]+$`

...?

Explaination:

`(?!.*[._-]{2})` // string must not contain two punctuation characters (`.`, `_` or `-`) together.

`[\w.-]+` // at least 1 allowed character (A-Z a-z 0-9 _ . or -)